# Requesting for a clientaccesspolicy file in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, file, policy

I want to know if it is possible to specifically send a request to get the clientaccesspolicy.xml file in Silverlight? Say the server is offline to begin with and the client does not get the policy file on start. This gets cached and all further requests fail.

I want to send a GET request to the server and request for the policy file periodically. Will it be ok to do this or do I have no option but to restart the application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that usecase is not currently supported in Silverlight 4.

It is a fairly well-known issue and hopefully Microsoft will take it upon themselves to fix it in Silverlight vNext. If you're passionate about fixing this issue consider voting for it up on [Uservoice](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/306114-security-policy-download-file-failure-never-retr).

Comment: Oh that's not good. So basically once I get a security exception for no policy file, any further requests will be dis-allowed including any to get the policy file. Thanks for sharing the uservoice link, I have voted for this change. However I'm using silverlight 3 and this change is going to force me to move to 4 i think.

Comment: To clarify, the last few comments in the silverlight forum discussion, say that it is available in Silverlight 4. You mention that it is not yet supported. Is there any official documentation where I can confirm this before moving from 3 to 4 ?

Comment: Seems like i'm talking to myself: It does work on SL4. Request for crossdomain.xml is made every 60 seconds. And for OOB elevating the trust level means that there is no request for any policy file. Now I have an issue with the crossdomain.xml but will start a new thread for it. Thanks